# Model mismatch and bias in Smith Predictors

Tags: control-engineering, control-theory

I have a question pertaining to Smith Predictors (see below for reference). Given a plant **P** and plant model **Gp**, I believe model mismatch is irrelevant in steady state. In steady state, delay-less plant model **yp** and delayed plant model **y1** approaches zero, thereby not making an impact to the error **e**. Only in the transient response, will model mismatch play a significant role here. Please correct me if I wrong.

My question pertains to accumulative model error. Lets say there is a large bias between plant output **y** and delayed plant model output **y1**. I believe this bias also is also irrelevant. I have a contact-force control application, whereby the control signal is motor velocity and plant output is contact force. If the end-effector were to begin not in-contact with an external wall, **y** would remain 0 whilst **yp** would be non-zero, thereby introducing a bias, until contact is made. I do not think this bias is a problem. Correct?

[image]